# change character_set_connection utf8mb4 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I want to change character_set_connection utf8mb4. Its showing me utf8. I have follow this https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 article and changed

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Also fire this query.

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

but when I check current status using

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character_set_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

result

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
collation_connection utf8_general_ci
collation_database latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server latin1_swedish_ci
```

I have set alter tables and database

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;  
ALTER DATABASE openfire CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  
ALTER TABLE ofOffline CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This is my connections string

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true
```

MySQL  5.6.33 I have check in windows with version 5.7.14 it's fine. Please give me any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were the `SET NAMES` and `SHOW` done from the _same_ connection?

Comment: @RickJames I got the solution, problem is from phpMyAdmin. I can see those values from mysql command prompt.

Comment: Is it a bug in phpmyadmin?  If so, file a bug report.  If not, then explain the solution for other users.  Or delete the Question.

Comment: @RickJames see Jamie wrote on 11th May 2013 at 16:59:  in https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4. as per the conversion it's bug

Comment: That's a long blog; can you summarize the part that solved your Question.

Comment: @RickJames fine this line Jamie wrote on 11th May 2013 at 16:59 you see conversation. Solution is just fire those sql queries and set  above setting in config file. Then I have check SHOW VARIABLES query in command prompt to check current character set instead of myAdmin and I can see character_set_client  utf8mb4